# How to display choices as checkboxes in django?

Tags: django

I have a model which i am overriding in `forms.py` and displaying in frontend. So choices field is coming as drop down but i want it to render as checkbox, i tried to do so by overriding in form with `forms.CheckBoxInput()` but its just showing checkbox for region hot for its respective options.so can please guide me how to achieve it.

models.py

```
region_choices = (
    ('AF', 'Africa'),
    ('AS', 'Asia'),
    ('EU', 'Europe'),
    ('NA', 'North America'),
    ('SA', 'South America'),
    ('OC', 'Oceania'),
    ('AN', 'Antarctica'),
)

class Registeration(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField()
    password = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    confirm_pasword = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    region = models.CharField(choices=region_choices,max_length=10)
    terms_confirmed = models.BooleanField(default=False)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

forms.py

```
class RegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super(RegistrationForm,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.fields['region'].widget = forms.CheckboxInput()


    class Meta:
        model = Registeration
        fields = '__all__'
```

html

```
<form>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}
    <input type="submit" value="ok">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `forms.MultipleChoiceField` with `widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple()`.

```
class RegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):

    region = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=region_choices, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())

    def clean_region(self):
        if len(self.cleaned_data['region']) > 1:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Select only 1 option.')
        return self.cleaned_data['region']

    class Meta:
        model = Registeration
        fields = '__all__'
```

or

```
class RegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super(RegistrationForm,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.fields['region']= forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=region_choices, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())

    def clean_region(self):
        if len(self.cleaned_data['region']) > 1:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Select only 1 option.')
        return self.cleaned_data['region']

    class Meta:
        model = Registeration
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: hi thanks,it works, but i want user to choose one option not multiple so how to do that?

Comment: @ChidanandaNayak Updated please check. You need to validate the submitted field in it's clean method as such.

Comment: @ChidanandaNayak Since you wanted one option to be selected, you might want to take a look at `RadioSelect() ` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/widgets/#widgets-inheriting-from-the-select-widget

Comment: thanks, so i did this `region = forms.ChoiceField(choices=region_choices, widget=forms.RadioSelect())` and it worked

Comment: Yup. Happy to help.